# Appending a dynamic string to values in list

Tags: python

I've got a list of values and I'd like to append a string to each one, however, the first value will need a different string than the rest. So given a list,

```
names = ['John', 'Jack', 'Kelly']
```

How can I get

```
'first comes John' 'then Jack' 'then Kelly'
```

I've tried doing a list comprehension but it didn't work out the way I was hoping. It ends up doing the else portion and completely neglecting the if portion.

```
newnames = []
for i in range(0, len(names)):
    if i == 0:
        c = ['first comes %s'%s for s in names[i]]
    else:
        c = ['then %s'%s for s in names[i]]
```

Comment: Here you override `c` each time, and `newnames` remains untouched. Furthermore you do not need list comprehension here. `names[i]` is a single name, so that means that `s` will be a character.

Comment: Do you want the results in a single string, or in a new list of strings, or the existing list called names to be modified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* use list comprehension here, but your current program simply shows a wrong algorithm.

`i` iterates over the *indices* of the `names` list, so that means that `names[i]` is a single name (string). As a result if you write `for c in names[i]`, `c` will iterate over the *characters* of a single name.

Let us first drop the requirement of list comprehension and write it like:

```
newnames = []
for i in range(0, len(names)):
    if i == 0:
        newnames.append('first comes %s' % names[i])
    else:
        newnames.append('then %s' % names[i])
```

So we `append` the formatted string to `newnames` and format the `names[i]`, not `c`.

We can however convert this to list comprehension with:

```
[('then %s' if i else 'first comes %s') % name for i, name in enumerate(names)]
```

What we here do is using `enumerate(..)` to yield tuples containing both the index `i`, and the `name` at that index. In case the *truthiness* of `i` is `True` (for numbers that means that it is *not* zero, we can use `'then %s'`, else we use `'first comes %s'`. We format that string with `name`.

We can boost performance by removing the *if* for every element and write it like:

```
['first comes %s' % name for  name in names[:1]] \
    + ['then %s' % name for name in names[1:]]
```

Here we use `names[:1]` which will yield at most one element, but the advantage is that if the list is empty, we will not get an error.

Or we can for instance work with functions:

```
from itertools import chain, islice

result = list(chain(
                 map('first comes {}'.format, islice(names, 1),
                 map('then {}'.format, islice(names, 1, None)
              ))
```

Comment: Noticed you used % format instead of format(). Personal preference or just following OP's code?

Comment: @SteveWilhelm: `.format(..)` of course, since `%` is a bit "*overflexible*", but the question used `%`, so I had the idea that it is better not to introduce additional items.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest this:

```
["here comes " + names[0]] + ["then " + name for name in names[1:]]
```

It works and it seems readable enough.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a list comprehension in combination with [**`enumerate()`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
names = ['John', 'Jack', 'Kelly']

new_names = ['first comes {}'.format(name) 
    if idx == 0 else 'then {}'.format(name)
    for idx, name in enumerate(names)]

print(new_names)
```

This yields

```
['first comes John', 'then Jack', 'then Kelly']
```